# MDX How to use CASE to check a level value

Tags: case, mdx

I'm new to BI and MDX and have a need to do this. I have a dimension that looks like this:

```
<Dimension name="JobDim">
    <Hierarchy name="Job" hasAll="true" primaryKey="jobID">
        <Table name="JobDim" schema="dw"/>
        <Level name="Job Code" column="jobCode" type="String" uniqueMembers="false"/>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Job Status" hasAll="true" primaryKey="jobID">
        <Table name="JobDim" schema="dw"/>
        <Level name="Job Status" column="status" type="String" hideMemberIf="IfBlankName"/>
    </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>
```

I have a calculated measure and I need to set the value of this measure depending on the 'job status', so if the job is 'complete', set the measure to 100, otherwise set its value to 200 (the value to be used is more complex but for this example purpose, this is good enough). I'm using something like this:

```
    <CalculatedMember name="Earned Revenue" dimension="Measures" formatString="$#,###.00;($#,###.00)" aggregator="sum">
        <Formula>case [JobDim.Job Status].CurrentMember
                    when [JobDim.Job Status].[Complete] then 100
                    else 200
                 end
        </Formula>
    </CalculatedMember>
```

I've tried different variations of the code above, but none seem to work (some even cause a crash when I try to run the report). Anyone has done something like this in the past that can provide me an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate that tuple against some measure. Remember that in MDX evaluations are done against the level/aggregate results, not on a row by row basis.

From your description it looks like Job Status should be a property of the level Job Code, and not a level.

Try the following on your schema:

`<Dimension name="JobDim">
    <Hierarchy name="Job" hasAll="true" primaryKey="jobID">
        <Table name="JobDim" schema="dw"/>
        <Level name="Job Code" column="jobCode" type="String" uniqueMembers="false">
            <Property name="Job Status" column="status" type="String"/>
        </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>`

and on your calculated measure

`<CalculatedMember name="Earned Revenue" dimension="Measures" formatString="$#,###.00;($#,###.00)" aggregator="sum">
        <Formula>case [JobDim.Job Status].CurrentMember.Properties("Job Status")
                    when "Complete" then 100
                    else 200
                 end
        </Formula>
</CalculatedMember>`

Comment: nsousa:Sadly it's a requirement to have 'job status' as a separate hierarchy in the same dimension so that's out of the question.

I managed to use this formula for my requirement:

case when [JobDim.Job Status].CurrentMember.Properties("MEMBER_KEY") = "Complete"
                        then [something]
                        else [something_else]
                     end

But I came to the conclusion that I needs to expose the values used in the formula in the cube for it to work. Otherwise I get an error message.

Thanks

Comment: You can keep it BOTH as a separate hierarchy and as a property of that level. If you can't absolutely use it as a property (can't see why), then you can instead use a condition such as [JobDim.Job Status].CurrentMember.Name = "Completed", but you will need to have both Job Status and Job code in your rowset.

Comment: nsoussa: Reason why it can't be just a Property is cause our customers want to slice by the status, therefore we have to keep it as a hierarchy. Is there a way to make this work without having to add the job status to the report?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `IIF` than `CASE` if possible as it is generally quicker. Assuming `[JobDim.Job Status].[Complete]` is a member in your cube then the `IS` operator should be ok to use:

```
IIF( 
     [JobDim.Job Status].CurrentMember
                    IS [JobDim.Job Status].[Complete]
     ,100
     ,200
)
```

Comment: whytheq: I didn't know that use of iif() was better than case; I'll definitely change my formulas to use iif() instead. I've tested your formula and it works well for me, but in order for this to work, I need to add the 'job status' field to the report. Is this a must?